# Use a VBA function inside a sort macro

Tags: excel, vba, function, sorting

I maintain an Excel spreadsheet with data in multiple columns that can be sorted in various ways as each user deems useful. I set this up using macros with buttons on the sheets that do the various sorts

A user has requested the ability to sort on a column that has letter-number combinations, but sort by number only. The data is aircraft callsigns that contain 1 to 3 letters followed by 1 to 5 numbers. The user wants to sort by flight number with no regard to the registration letters.

I found a function that accomplishes this called "num()". I would like to use this function without altering the data in the column itself. Here's an example of what I'm shooting for:

```
Sub sortscenarionum()
'
' sortscenarionum Macro
' Sort Aircraft by FLIGHT NUMBER then RPO TIME
'
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "N11:N159"), SortOn:=num("N11:N159"), Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "I11:I159"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range("B11:N159")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    SendKeys "{ESC}"
End Sub
```

This fails with "Type mismatch". I have also tried SortOn:=num(xlSortValues) with the same negative results. I have no problem with moving the function into the macro itself, but I have no idea how to do that. Here's the function in case it's useful:

```
Function num(rng As Range) As String
Dim n As Integer
For n = 1 To Len(rng)
If Mid(rng, n, 1) Like "[0-9]" Then
num = num & Mid(rng, n, 1)
End If
Next n
End Function
```

Comment: Are you certain `num` is always returning a value? Add a `Debug.Print num` line before you sort and see what it's giving you.

Comment: 1. num is written for only one cell not a range of cells.  I think you will need to add the output of num to another column and sort on that column.

Comment: It looks like to me you are passing a string to `num` but the function expects a range.

Comment: Agree with @ScottCraner - add an extra column that is just the flight number without the airline prefix. Hide that column from the users so they don't see it/get confused by it. Sort that column via macro.

Comment: The NUM function worked perfectly for what it was. The only problem with it is it's slow. Turned out I didn't need it based on the answer below. I did think of adding the extra column but 200+ pages in this workbook would have taken some time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a column to be used as a helper; populate then sort on the new column; delete the new column.

```
Sub sortscenarionum()
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        .Columns("O").Insert
        With .Range(.Cells(11, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1))
            .Columns(.Columns.Count).Formula = "=numsOnly(N11)"
            .Columns(.Columns.Count).Value = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Value
            .Sort Key1:=.Columns(.Columns.Count), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                  Key2:=.Columns(8), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                  Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
        End With
        .Columns("O").Delete
    End With
End Sub

Function numsOnly(str As String)    
    'with rgx as static, it only has to be created once
    Static rgx As Object
    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    End If
    numsOnly = vbNullString

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "[0-9]{1,5}$"
        If .test(str) Then
            numsOnly = CLng(.Execute(str)(0))
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Awesome! I only had to add Unprotect and Protect to the sheet. Also, I meant to use the B column as the source for the sort, but that as simple as changing  "=numsOnly(N11)" to  "=numsOnly(B11)"

I wrote one myself in the interim that encased the function in the macro, but it ran ssssllllooowww... Like one cell every 2 seconds.

Thanks a lot for your help.